# how to add node version to zsh prompt with prezto

Tags: node.js, terminal, zsh, prezto

I'm not too versed with the terminal. I'm using zsh with prezto and I wanted to show the node version in the prompt. At the prezto repo they provide these instructions:
https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/tree/master/modules/node

And I can follow up to the last part:

> Then add $node_info[version] to either $PROMPT or $RPROMPT and call node-info in prompt_name_preexec hook function.

I added $node_info[version] to the $PROMPT in my theme file, but what does it mean to call node-info in the prompt_name_preexec hook? is that a function inside my theme file? I honestly have no clue what is talking about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple files associated with `Zsh` prompt themes, Like 
`prompt_name_setup`, `prompt_name_preview`, `prompt_name_help`, `prompt_name_preexec`. Only `prompt_name_setup` is required and others are optional, These files are stored somewhere in `$fpath`. Replace that `name` with your current prompt theme (`prompt -c`).

To show your `node` version in `prezto`, Add the following to your `prompt_name_setup`.

```
zstyle ':prezto:module:node:info:version' format 'version:%v'
```

Create if you don't have a file named `prompt_name_preexec` in your `$fpath` or add this to it as `PROMPT` or `RPROMPT` variable.

```
$node_info[version]
```

After reloading your terminal, Verify its added by `echo $PROMPT` or `echo $RPROMPT`.

---

If you don't want any of the hassle and want to show `node` version in your prompt, Use a prompt theme like [spaceship-prompt](https://git.io/spaceship) (Disclaimer: I'm one of the maintainer)

Answer (score 0):

One can add 
`PS1+="$(node --version)"` to the `$PS1` variable to display current node version

Comment: That's cool, but it won't refresh if you change node versions during an existing shell session, say with a tool like `nvm use lts/iron`.